# xmlHttpRequest issue

Tags: javascript, xml, checkbox, xmlhttprequest, alert

I am using Js xmlHttpRequest to display the same menu on different pages of my site. Lately I found out that some functions are not executed when the site is online, like a quiz I made.

I had also tried to use fetch, or put the scripts in different files, but the same thing kept happening.

(The quiz does work when checking locally, where the xml request cannot be satisfied.)

```js
//load the menu
onload = function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML +=
        this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "mnu.html", true);
    xhttp.send();
  }
  
  //check the quiz
  const checkBtn = document.getElementById('checkBtn')
checkBtn.onclick = function quizCheck() {
    //right answers
    var score = 0;
    if (q1a1.checked) {
        score = score + 1;
    }
    if (q2a1.checked) {
        score = score + 1;
    }
    alert("your score: " + score);
}
```

```html
<li>
    Check the right answer:
        <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="q1a1">Right
        <br>
    <input type="checkbox">Wrong
</li>

<li>
    Check the right answer:
        <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="q2a1">Right
        <br>
    <input type="checkbox">Wrong
</li>

<button id="checkBtn">Check</button>
```

Anybody knows why and/or has some solutions?

Comment: What is `"mnu"` ? The second argument to `.open()` should be the URL to make the request to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line which is wrong and that's why js is not working.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += this.responseText;
```

You can't just add to innerHtml like that.
Instead you should create an html element and add it to body like this:

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerText = this.responseText;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

edit: of course you want to add an html menu instead of just a text inside a `<p>`, so you will have to add it like this:

```
var nav = document.createElement('nav');
nav.innerHTML = this.responseText;
document.body.prepend(nav); // always at the top
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm. Though your way made more sense, why did mine blocked some functions?

Comment: From what i can tell, doing it the way you did, completely replaces the contents of body, and then recreates it from the existing html "string" while also adding the extra string. This means that existing html elements with their event handlers are not preserved. If you try to add the code for getting the checkBtn, and adding the event handler after you added to innerHtml it will work. But this is not recommended.